# hadoop distcp permission denied error while executing "distcp" command with non-super user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I am trying to do inter cluster data copying between two clusters using hadoop distcp and the command would be executed using user which doesnt have any permissions,only super user has all file permissions(777),is there a way to solve this problem

```
command executed on shell:
hadoop distcp hdfs://[cluster1]:9000/home/[usr1]/data1 hdfs://[cluster2]:9000/home/[usr1]/data2

Error:
ERROR [main] tools.DistCp (DistCp.java:run(162)) - Exception encountered
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=[usr1], access=EXECUTE, inode="/tmp":[superuser]:supergroup:drwxrwx---
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:350)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkTraverse(FSPermissionChecker.java:311)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1751)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1735)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkOwner(FSDirectory.java:1680)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirAttrOp.setPermission(FSDirAttrOp.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermission(FSNamesystem.java:1777)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setPermission(NameNodeRpcServer.java:830)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:469)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:871)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:817)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1889)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2606)
```

Comment: Can you run a YARN job with `usr1`  ?

Comment: I can't run any yarn job as usr1 doesn't have rwx permissions  for /tmp folder of hdfs

Comment: well, run a `hdfs -dfs chmod 777 /tmp` from super user

Comment: is there no other option than enabling permissions as I have made it clear in my question itself

Comment: your question as unclear actually. As for a Unix FS, you need to make /tmp accessible to all users